# how add a row to dataframe spark scala with different schema?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, pivot

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
    ---------------------------------------
    id | k  | v1  | v2     | v3           |
    1  |sc1 | ok  |null    | null         |
    1  |sc2 | no  |null    | null         |
    1  |sc3 | yes |null    | null         |
    1  |sc4 |null |20180318| null         |
    1  |sc5 |null |null    | ["5","2","9"]|
    1  |sc6 |null |20180317|null          |
    1  |sc7 |ok++ |null    |null          |
    2  |sc3 |yes++|null    |null          |
    2  |sc2 |no-- |null    |null          |
    2  |sc7 |ok-- |null    |null          |
    2  |sc4 |null |20180315|null          |
    3  |sc1 | no  |null    |null          |
    3  |sc6 |null |20180313|null          |
    .
    .
```

I want to get this result

```
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    id|  sc1 |sc2 |sc3  |sc4     |sc5          |sc6     |sc7 | sc8 |sc9 | ...  |sck
    1 |ok    |no  |yes  |20180318|["5","2","9"]|20180317|ok++|     |    |      |
    2 |      |no--|yes++|20180315|             |        |ok--|     |    | .... |
    3 |no    |    |     |        |             |20180313|    |     |    | .... |
    .
    .
    n |ok++  |    |yes  |        |["1","0","1"]|        |    |     |ok++| ...  |ok++
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so I tried to use `df.groupby("id").pivot("k")` but I did not get a result I think that because the schema variable in each when i work with only one id it work for example with id==1

```
     |  sc1 |sc2 |sc3  |sc4     |sc5          |sc6     |sc7 |
   1 |ok    |no  |yes  |20180318|["5","2","9"]|20180317|ok++|
```

is there a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need to create a new column that combines v1,v2 and v3 based on the one that isn't null and the pivot on k

something like

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*

val choose = udf((x: String, y: String,z : Array[Int]) => (x,y,z) match {
  case (v, null, null) => v
  case (null,v,null) => v
  case (null,null,v) => v.toString
})

df.groupby("id").pivot("k").agg(first(choose(v1,v2,v3)))
```

Comment: Thanks Arnon it works but my dataframe become have large number of column :11000 when I want to save it to Mongodb or simple show give me error but when I select a specific column it works also when i print schema it works or df.count() also works, I don't know whet I should do.